# Remove Outlook email attachments for pst file

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

How can save all of the attachments from an Outlook 2010 archive?  Is there a cheap method to do this?

Comment: Do you want to remove them or save them?  The title and question seem to be at odds as to your objective.

Answer (score 1):

One free method is to use VBA but it would be best to try utilities I've mentioned below.  It should be simple enough to write the code but there will be several things to consider, such as 2 items below.

1) Best to suffix filenames with date & time in case you get 2 attachments with the same filename.

2) Probably best to self-certify the code so that it will run.

Unfortunately, you will need moderate proficiency with VBA.

Some example code here to do what you need for current Inbox. So would need to be changed to look in the Archive file.
http://www.fontstuff.com/outlook/oltut01.htm

If you aren't good with VBA then Nirsoft's OutlookAttachView utility might work.  I think it only looks at the current PST file so you might have to alter Outlook to make the Archive the default PST whilst using the utility.
Try http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_attachment.html

You could also try Kopf Add-in http://www.kopf.com.br/outlook/  It is free and should let you select a specific source folder.

These are the only 3 options I know about offhand but others might come up with better solutions.